# Compression with Restlet + Jetty embedded

Tags: jetty, restlet, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin, restlet-2.0

I'm trying to enable the compression in restlet + jetty embedded but in my test application the compression works only with requests handled directly by servlets and not for those handled by restlet.

My test code:

```java
package restlettest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.EnumSet;

import javax.servlet.DispatcherType;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter;
import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;

public class RestletTestServerJettyEmbedded {

    public static class RestletTestApplication extends Application {

        @Override
        public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {

            Router router = new Router(getContext());
            router.attach("/sayHello", HelloWorldResource.class);

            return router;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static class JettyServlet extends HttpServlet {

        @Override
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws ServletException, IOException {

            resp.getWriter().println("Hello from jetty!");
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Server server = new Server(8080);

        final ServletContextHandler serveltContext = new ServletContextHandler(
                ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        serveltContext.setContextPath("/");
        serveltContext.setInitParameter("org.restlet.application",
                RestletTestApplication.class.getName());

        serveltContext.addFilter(GzipFilter.class, "/*",
                EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST));

        serveltContext.addServlet(ServerServlet.class, "/restlet/*");
        serveltContext.addServlet(JettyServlet.class, "/jetty/*");

        server.setHandler(serveltContext);

        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

The project POM:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.devmao.restlettest</groupId>
    <artifactId>restlettest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>

        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <jetty.version>8.1.7.v20120910</jetty.version>
        <restlet.version>2.1.0</restlet.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jetty -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlets</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /Jetty -->

        <!-- Restlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${restlet.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- /Restlet -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>

        <!-- Restlet Repositories -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven-restlet</id>
            <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- /Restlet Repositories -->

    </repositories>
</project>
```

Testing servlet request:

```
$ curl -i -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://localhost:8080/jetty
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(8.1.7.v20120910)
```

Testing restlet request:

```
$ curl -i -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' http://localhost:8080/restlet/sayHello
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 06 Nov 2012 09:24:01 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Restlet-Framework/2.1.0
Vary: Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
Content-Length: 12
```